# Why does Browserify only export one of these jQuery variables?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

The entry point file for my Browserify bundling contains only one line:

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Why is it that this only exports `jQuery` as a variable to the global scope, and not `$` as `jQuery` as well?

I'm using Gulp to do my browserify - here is the appropriate code in my gulpfile:

```
/** Vendor compilation */                                                               
.task('vendor', ['clean'], function() {  
  // package.paths.vendor is my one line file referenced above                                               
  var b = browserify(package.paths.vendor);                                             
  getBowerPackageIds().forEach(function (id) {                                          

    var resolvedPath = bowerResolve.fastReadSync(id);                                   

    b.require(resolvedPath, {                                                           

      // exposes the package id, so that we can require() from our code.                
      // for eg:                                                                        
      // require('./vendor/angular/angular.js', {expose: 'angular'}) enables require('angular');
      // for more information: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#brequirefile-opts
      expose: id

    });
  });                                                                                   
  return b                                                                              
  .bundle()                                                                             
  .pipe(source(package.dest.vendor))                                                    
  .pipe(gulp.dest(package.dest.dist));                                                  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
```

defines a local variable, `$`, and a global variable, `jQuery`.

You could use this instead:

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');
```

to define both `$` and `jQuery` as globals.